# Can employer withhold website pay because I submitted notice?

Tags: united-states, work-time

I've been at a small tech co in N.E. Oklahoma (US) for three years. I'm the only web developer. Turned in two weeks notice last week. On Thursday, I talked with the office manager, who functions as our boss's right-hand person.

I referenced two screen captures I had emailed to her: One showing my 33 hours on a mostly-done website project, before all the electronic time sheets were migrated to shared database managed by our new corporate owners.

The second capture showed the website project as it appears now in the corporate location; all the hours zeroed out. (There was a previous incident where a client went over our max number of work hours for a fixed-price site, and the boss wanted to make me absorb the loss.)

She said "Yeah I'm going to move a couple of those [hours] over." Then she tried to get me to pressure the client into finishing the site before I'm gone, because... "If you don't get it done, then we won't be able to pay you for the project."

Related: They tried something similar on a past co-worker, and he was only able to get his wages after going to a federal agency.

Comment: Sorry, probably a matter for US lawyers.

Comment: @MichaelMcFarlane, Not at all. In the US, if you're a W2 employee and your employer committed wage theft, you don't need a lawyer to recover your money. See my answer.

Comment: Are you in the US? Can you please add a location tag? As you can see, people are already engaging in wild guesses about it, please make sure you get appropriate answers by adding a tag and stop the guesswork.

Comment: This should be taken to a lawyer, or at least to the law stack; legal issues are off topic here. I hope you manage to get your money out of them.

Comment: "Can an employer withhold pay?" - Generally not, but you'll need to tell us where you're located in order to give you relevant answers.

Comment: I am confused as to your employment status. Are you an employee who will get W-2 at the end of the year, or are you a contractor who will get a 1099 at the end of the year?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I acknowledge your helpful answer.

Answer (score 20):

In the US, you can just go to the Labor Department of your State. If you live in the US and tell us which State you're in, I can find you the link and the right contact information. Assuming you are really a W2 worker (and not just a contractor), wage theft is taken very seriously.

In California, if you file your claim before the company can file for bankruptcy, they even have the power of going after the personal assets of the board of Directors. And once you file your claim, they can't retaliate against you for six months (at least in California). Again, you'll have to tell us the jurisdiction you're in. The details may vary based on your exact jurisdiction.

Be sure to document everything. And keep that documentation at home, in case they no longer give you access to your office.

Comment: I was recruited with an offer of heading up the boss's new web services department. This was originally marketed under a different name than his already-established tech shop. He predicted we would eventually add two more techs, and possibly spin this off entirely. The one oddity I first noticed was that he would not hire a salesman. That meant a very small number of customers, and those mostly due to his existing positive reputation in other technologies. Then he and his accountant started emphasizing the word contractor. This is rapidly becoming one of those hindsight things.

Comment: @user722951 what does your contract say?

Comment: @user722951, Don't jump to conclusions. You can still be a contractor and an employee, if the intermediary pays you with a W2 or if your contract says you're an employee. How did you have to declare your taxes to the IRS? That should tell you if you're an employee or a contractor.

Comment: Thanks to Everyone who responded. I did document everything, because a good web developer tracks the details. Moving this to another venue! Thanks again!

Comment: @user722951, And even if they classified you as an independent contractor, it's possible that they misclassified you. https://www.emw-sandiego-attorney.com/blog/businesses-classifying-developers-under-california-law.html (again, this is assuming you're in California). Misclassification carries its own set of fines for the employer.